# C# progres bar and background worker issue

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have reviewed similar questions and found no answer there.

1/ I am running external file from my C# form. It is wrapped to function:

```
    private void SimulatestartTask()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "test.exe";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

2/ I have my background workers method written like this:

```
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {   
SimulatestartTask();

                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
                {

                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exx)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
                MessageBox.Show("C Sharp is NOT awesome." + exx);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

I got error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> The thread 0x4b5c has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown:
>    'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>    'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.dll Exception thrown:
>    'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll

I am lost at this point, could somebody help?

Comment: Not sure what your asking, SimulatestartTask starts the exe, you call it 100 times in a loop so it starts it 100 times ...

Comment: What do you expect, when calling `SimulatestartTask` 100 times. It of course will start the process once per method-call, yielding to 100 process-calls. Do you want to report the progress of that process? I doubt this is possible, as the process itself does not provide any information about its progress. How would an external caller know how far the process proceeded so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can only report progress between itterations of a loop. Wich either requires somebody elses code specially designed to hand out those notifications (some newer asynch call functions do). Or doing the whole code down to the lowest loop from scratch.

I did write an example where I had control over the full code, so I could do progress reporting freely:

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```

If the programm was a console programm writing the current progress to the console, you might be able to read it out using Input Redirection. But other wise there is two layers between you and the running progress to get any notification from.

Anotehr problem I noticed is you exception handling. You catch exception and do not let it go on, wich is a deadly sin of exception handling. The BGW will already take care of catching and exposing any exxceptions that might happen in teh DoWork code. Doing so again - especially by showing a MessageBox - is not a good idea at all. Here are two articles I link often on exception handling. You should propably read them:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET